# PostgreSQL: Autofill columns values by applying math to other values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

On PostgreSQL (using pgAdmin4) I'm trying to make some columns autofill values based on math being applied to other values in the same and/or other table(s). Given the tables below, I want to set :

`purchases.subtotal = purchases.quantity * prices.price`, on `prices.item_id = purchases.item_id`

and

`purchases.total = purchases.subtotal - (purchases.subtotal * discount);`
(*discount* being a value between 0 and 1.)

How does one program a formula to determine a column's value per row?

Prices:

```
item_id |  name  | price 
-------------------
   1    |  item1 | 2.00
```

Purchases:

```
id | item_id | quantity | subtotal | discount | total
-----------------------------------------------------
1  |    1    |     7    |     x    |    y     |   z
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate it while inserting the values in table `purchases`? if yes then `discount` value which is between 0 to 1 will be entered by user?

Answer (score 3):

One method is a view:

```
create view v_purchases
    select p.*, (p.quantity * pr.price) as subtotal,
           (p.quantity * pr.price) * (1 - p.discount) as total
    from purchases p join
         products pr
         on p.item_id = pr.item_id;
```

Comment: thanks, but is there no way to do this is a permanent table?

Comment: @idanicoleherbert . . . Not easily.  Even with a generated column (now available in the most recent versions of Postgres), you would need a user-defined function to fetch the product price.

Comment: You could use a trigger or a materialized view.